# Perforce client connecting to server WSAETIMEDOUT

Tags: windows, windows-7, perforce

I've been ripping my hair out for a few days over this and need help. I have a perforce server and an external client. Steps I've taken:

```
1. Opened port 1666 on my router (TCP and UDP) for my servers IP.
2. Allowed port 1666 through windows firewall.
3. I can connect to the perforce server from any system on the LAN by hostname or IP.
4. NETSTAT -a shows port 1666 is LISTENING.
5. External client can ping the server by external IP.
6. Internal client can telnet to the internal IP and port, external cannot.
```

I can not for the life of me figure out why the hell my external client cannot connect to the server. I am getting my external IP from "WhatsMyIP.org" and it matches my routers WAN address.

I have full on tried to disable windows firewall and still the same issue.

Please god someone help before I lose the rest of my hair.

**EDIT1: I forgot to mention the error I am receiving from the external client:**

```
Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
TCP connect to 99.252.60.60:1666 failed.
connect: 99.252.60.60:1666: WSAETIMEDOUT
```

Comment: What's the server's P4PORT?  ("p4 set -S Perforce P4PORT", if you're running it as a service called "Perforce")

Comment: @Sam Stafford: Yes, the service is called "Perforce" and set p4port says: "Enviromental variable p4port not defined."

EDIT: I ran your command and it says: "P4PORT=1666 (set -S)"

Comment: That sounds correct -- I was wondering if the server itself were limiting itself to local connections, but with a plain port number it'll accept connections on that port no matter where they come from.

Comment: If the external client cannot telnet to that IP and port, perhaps the problem lies on the external client, or on a piece of network equipment along the way. Traceroute from the external client to that IP, and see what intermediate gateways and routers you are going through?

Comment: Are you port forwarding 1666 from your router to your server?

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Yes, I am port forwarding port 1666 to my internal server.

Comment: Have you tried 'ping' or 'telnet'? Here are troubleshooting Hints for that error message: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2960

Comment: @P4Shimada Please, read my post before posting a comment. Yes I can ping the server, and no, I cannot telnet to the server from the external client. I've gone through the page that you've linked before creating this question as that was the only information I could find for troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: @Blankdud You definitely sounded irritated. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working at this for three days, I found the issue with help from this forum post:

http://208.74.204.155/t5/forums/forumtopicpage/board-id/Getting_connected/thread-id/8923/page/1

My router model (Hitron Technologies CGN2-ROG) that I received from my ISP (Rogers up here in Canada) apparently doesn't play nice when it comes to port forwarding. With all of the EXACT same settings, I bridged that router to another spare I had laying around and it worked perfectly.

I literally just plugged in the new router and it worked without making any other changes at all.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at your router's firewall rules in more detail.

I had a similar problem with my home setup that resulted in me having to modify some firewall settings on the router.

This KB also gives some information about the error:

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2960/