# I can't connect to my perforce server remotely; getting WSAETIMEDOUT error

Tags: networking, server, game-development, perforce

I am trying to setup a perforce server on a remote dedicated server, so that myself and a team can access it for game development.

I have followed the guides here https://help.perforce.com/helix-core/quickstart/Content/quickstart/admin-reference.html to setup the helix server as well as p4v itself.

As far as I can tell, I've set this all up correctly however when I tried to connect to the server I get the following error message:

```
Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT. TCP connect to 77.68.35.203:1666 failed. connect: 77.68.35.203:1666: WSAETIMEDOUT, A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Initially I googled the WSAETIMEDOUT timed out error and found this page with some troubleshooting tips: https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2960. I went through the first couple of troubleshooting tips but found I was unable to contact the server using the telnet command however I could ping the server IP itself.

So I'm not sure if there's something I need to do on the remote server side or if it's something I've setup incorrectly with perforce! I've opened all ports for 1666 inbound/outbound and that didn't seem to work either.

I've also double and triple checked my P4PORT values and ensuring I'm using the right server address etc..

I'm a complete noob when it comes to perforce, so please, any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

As a P.S
[Perforce client connecting to server WSAETIMEDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466548/perforce-client-connecting-to-server-wsaetimedout)

I also thought it could've been the above but I asked another member of our team (outside my home connection) and they couldn't connect either.

Comment: The easy way to double check that Perforce itself is running is to do `p4 -p 1666 info` on the server machine (so the client is just connecting to the server via localhost).  If that doesn't work, then either p4d isn't running or the server machine is blocking port 1666.  If it does work, then your problem is the network connection between the server and your clients.

Comment: That worked! Thanks Samwise, I'll get in touch with the server provider and see if we can troubleshoot it further!

Comment: My guess is that traffic on that port is blocked and you'll want to set up some kind of VPN to be able to open it up securely (you *can* just open the port up so any Internet rando can connect to it, but using a VPN or SSH tunnel that provides authentication and encryption is better).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting this. I have a similar issue and came across your post and it was a huge help in troubleshooting.

I just want to add one more solution that could possibly help resolve the issue.

For context, the root cause of my problem is that there is no Inbound Rule in my Windows Firewall settings for `p4d`

Here is what I did to solve it:

1. Open the **Advanced Settings** of Windows Firewall
2. Check if there is an **Inbound Rule** for `p4d`
3. For me, I do not have an Inbound Rule for `p4d` so I added a rule for it that allow connection for port 1666
4. After I added the Inbound Rule, I was able to allow public connection to my Helix Core Server

Hope this helps